# C# Generics Research Papers

Tags: pl.programming-languages

What are the most significant research papers on the foundations of generics in C# and .NET?

Comment: Hello @Kariem: This site is for research level questions in theoretical computer science, and your problem may not be in scope here. As a programming language related problem, maybe you can try [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) for help!

Comment: The question appears to be too unfocused.  I voted to close it as not a real question.  See also [how to ask a good question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @Hsien-Chih Chang, I did ask at SO but it was closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479523/c-generics-research-papers

Comment: This is really a software-engineering question.  I don't think they have an overflow-like website, but you won't find many SE experts here.

Comment: Kariem, I think it would help if you explain why this question is a theoretical computer science question. Only *theoretical* PL questions are on topic here.

Comment: @Derrick @Kaveh, I mean the design and implementation of Generics in C# and .NET. Maybe that didn't come through in my question. I think this is a programming languages research question. A good example is this paper that had the initial proposal for generics in C# and .NET: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=381694.378797

Comment: Kariem, this site is for **theoretical** computer science questions, I don't think that general PL questions like those related to *implementation* are on-topic here, so I am voting to close the question as off-topic. (ps: [your question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479523/c-generics-research-papers) is closed not because it is off-topic there but because of other issues, try to address them on SO and they will hopefully reopen your question.)

Comment: @Hsien-Chih Chang, please do not discourage people to ask programming language questions, [which are in scope](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/446/broadening-the-scope-of-questions). There's plenty of theory-heavy work in PL. See, eg, [this](http://www-2.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/crary/www/819-f09/Moggi89.pdf) and [this](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?cluster=7229327518917241732). (This particular question, though, sounds like "Could you point me to research in graph algorithms?", ie, it's vague.)

Comment: I vote to keep the question. If it weren't so late, I'd provide a an answer too. This is, potentially, about PL theory. More tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I have edited the question to make it less vague.

Comment: I do not know how the edit in revision 2 is supposed to make the question less vague.

Comment: @Radu: Sorry for the misleading comment, I am not intended to do so. What do I really want to say is that this problem is (currently) a reference request for papers in specific programming languages, which is not a theoretical problem (currently) and is [out of scope](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/115/1800) (Or it isn't? Maybe I am totally wrong here). I'd love to see if the question is being modified, and becomes a theory problem. Thank you all for pointing out my wrong redirection, and @Kariem I hope you will get good answers here!

Comment: I answered the question assuming that you were asking for the foundations of C# generics. It would have been better to be more precise in your question. Were you after foundations? Implementations? Exotic uses of C# generics?

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. I was after the foundations of generics in C#. I edited the question to reflect that. Your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most of the important work on generics for C# was done by Andrew Kennedy at Microsoft Research Cambridge. He has a [web page](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/index.html) devoted to the topic. A fairly recent paper discussion the foundations is [this one](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64042/ecoop06.pdf) (which definitely looks like theory to me).

More recent, but interesting, work went into the design of [C$\omega$](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/comega/). Also looking at the rather large amount of literature on Java generics, such as [Featherweight Java](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.1141&rep=rep1&type=pdf), will also help. If you really want to start looking at the foundations, consider Cardelli's work on [Types and Semantics](http://lucacardelli.name/indexPapers.html#Types%20and%20Semantics), and perhaps consider looking at [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) (and the original papers of Reynolds and Girard).

Comment: Great answer. It reversed my vote on the question.  I still believe this is really software engineering, but definitely the more theoretic side.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. In mind, theoretical computer science is a continuum, which dips its PL theory end into software engineering. Also, in my mind software engineering is fuzzy with loads of UML diagrams.

Comment: Also by Andrew Kennedy on that subject is this paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/generics/designandimplementationofgenerics.pdf